# Why we use async/await in nodejs if it is already an asynchronous and in javascript also vice vera?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, synchronous

Sorry I am a noob and a  very beginner with Javascript and NodeJS. :(
Pardon me for asking this silly question.

So I am here a little bit confused. I searched a lot but didn't get the appropriate understanding. My question is simple:

> ```
> Javascript is synchronous and we use async/await for the callbacks.
> Nodejs is asynchronous but also then we use async/await nodejs also.
> ```

I really don't get this. How's is it happening? Maybe someone can give me a clear picture of this with some proper and easy to understand examples.
Thanks!

Comment: async/await is just a synchronous syntax to write asynchronous JS. It makes code more readable.

Comment: you should check out threads...

Comment: Where are you getting that quote? As far as I know Nodejs is every bit as synchronous as JavaScript.

Comment: *"Javascript is synchronous ... Nodejs is asynchronous"* That's some nonsense if ever read any. Where did you get this statement from?

Comment: 3 things: event loop,task que, job que. learn them how they work and you might understand javascript a little bit better

Answer (score 2):

Javascript and Nodejs, code written in both works synchronously. Based on functional requirement we make the execution of code asynchronous by adding async/await.